# Datatable not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

So I am generating a table with results which are returned from a JSON that is searched through and I would like to table to have pagionation, search, sorting options so I decided to use Data Tables. The table is being generated and populated with the correct results but the sorting options, the search and the pagination options do not appear at all. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Конкуренција</title>
</head>


<body>

<div id="cars" class="cars-container"></div>

<label for="amount">Цена:</label>
<input type="text" class="price-range-slider" id="amount"      onclick="myFunction()" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6932f; font-weight:bold">
<div id="slider-range" style="width:300px"></div>

<br>



    <p>
    <label for="sili">Коњски сили:</label>
    <input type="text" id="sili" onclick="myFunction()" readonly     style="border:0;  color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
<div id="rejndz" style="width:300px" ></div>
```

```
<div>
    <h4><label>Бренд</label></h4>
    <select id="brand" multiple="multiple" onclick="myFunction()" data-    style="btn-primary">
</select>

</div>
<br>

<div>
<h4><label>Тип на мотор</label></h4> 

<select id="engineCap" multiple="multiple" onclick="myFunction()" >

</select>
```

```
<button onclick="myFunction(); dataTable(); ">Барај</button>
```

```
</table>
var selected = [];
    var kapacitet = [];
    var cena = [];
    var hp = [];
    var niza = [];
    var finalKola = [];
function addTable() {
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "";
            var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("results")
            var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY')

            myTableDiv.border = '1'
            myTableDiv.appendChild(tableBody);  

            var heading = []; 
                    heading[0] = "Бренд"
                    heading[1] = "Модел"
                    heading[2] = "Капацитет"
                    heading[3] = "Коњски сили"
                    heading[4] = "Цена"


            //koloni 
            var tr = document.createElement('TR');
            tableBody.appendChild(tr);
            for (a = 0; a < heading.length; a++) {
                var th = document.createElement('TH')
                th.width = '75';
                th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(heading[a]));
                tr.appendChild(th);
            }

            //table rows
            for (a = 0; a < finalKola.length; a++) {
                var tr = document.createElement('TR'); 

                    var td = document.createElement('TD')
                    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(finalKola[a].Brand));
                    tr.appendChild(td);
                    var td = document.createElement('TD')
                    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(finalKola[a].Model));
                    tr.appendChild(td);
                    var td = document.createElement('TD')
                    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(finalKola[a].engineCap));
                    tr.appendChild(td);
                    var td = document.createElement('TD')
                    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(finalKola[a].sili));
                    tr.appendChild(td);
                    var td = document.createElement('TD')
                    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(finalKola[a].amount + " €"));
                    tr.appendChild(td);

                tableBody.appendChild(tr); 

            }

        $(document).ready(function (){
                        {
                            $('#results').dataTable();
                        }
                 });
        }
```

These are the errors I get in console:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined
    at HTMLTableCellElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:88)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:368)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:88)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:368)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:157)
    at jQuery.fn.init.p [as dataTable] (jquery.dataTables.min.js:80)
    at dataTable (index.html:268)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:75)`

Assigning value to finalKola in the following code. This code takes values from two range slider and two buttons and searches through a JSON.

```
for(var u=0;u<koli.length;u++)
    {
        if((koli[u].sili > minSili)  && (koli[u].sili < maxSili) && (parseInt(koli[u].amount.replace(',','')) > minCena) && (parseInt(koli[u].amount.replace(',','')) < maxCena))
        {

            if( (kapacitet.length > 0 && $.inArray(koli[u].engineCap,kapacitet) != -1) &&
            (selected.length > 0 && $.inArray(koli[u].Brand,selected) != -1))
            {
                finalKola.push(koli[u]);
            }   
            else if(kapacitet.length == 0 && selected.length == 0)
            {
                finalKola.push(koli[u]);
            }
            else if((kapacitet.length > 0 && $.inArray(koli[u].engineCap,kapacitet) != -1) &&
            (selected.length == 0))
            {
                finalKola.push(koli[u]);
            }
            else if((selected.length > 0 && $.inArray(koli[u].Brand,selected) != -1) &&
            (kapacitet.length == 0))
            {
                finalKola.push(koli[u]);
            }

        }           

    }
```

Comment: where is finalKola defined? cannot see it in your code

Comment: Harry, finalKola is defined at the very beginning of the script :)

Answer (score 0):

I think `DataTable` is not applying on your table as you are applying `datatable` on `$(document).ready` and creating table in your function.

You can apply `datatable` after you have created the table.

```
function addTable() {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "";
        var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("results")
        var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY')

        myTableDiv.border = '1'
        myTableDiv.appendChild(tableBody);

        var heading = [];
        heading[0] = "Бренд"
        heading[1] = "Модел"
        heading[2] = "Капацитет"
        heading[3] = "Коњски сили"
        heading[4] = "Цена"


        //koloni 
        var tr = document.createElement('TR');
        tableBody.appendChild(tr);
        for (a = 0; a < heading.length; a++) {
            var th = document.createElement('TH')
            th.width = '75';
            th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(heading[a]));
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }

        //table rows
        for (a = 0; a < finalKola.length; a++) {
            var tr = document.createElement('TR');

            var td = document.createElement('TD')
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(finalKola[a].Brand));
            tr.appendChild(td);
            var td = document.createElement('TD')
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(finalKola[a].Model));
            tr.appendChild(td);
            var td = document.createElement('TD')
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(finalKola[a].engineCap));
            tr.appendChild(td);
            var td = document.createElement('TD')
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(finalKola[a].sili));
            tr.appendChild(td);
            var td = document.createElement('TD')
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(finalKola[a].amount + " €"));
            tr.appendChild(td);

            tableBody.appendChild(tr);

        }
            $('#results').dataTable().fnDestroy();
            $('#results').dataTable();
    }
```

Comment: I tried this, still nothing. thank you for your time though :)

Comment: can you post your html? datatable require well formatted tbody and thead, the error seems to be related with the HTML Table format. colspan, no of columns etc.

Comment: I only use the following for the html code. The rows and columns are generated by the function for the table. 

<table id="results" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover ">

</table>

Comment: My guess is you need to add a `<thead>` as well. And stop using all upper-case HTML tags.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie yes `thead` is needed but as OP is saying table in being created fine so Upper case doesn't see to be an issue.

Comment: Yes, the table is being generated and populated with the correct results. I just don't get the option to sort the table, to search the table and the pagination options...

Comment: @noc32 add `thead` as well and check.

Comment: No, there is nothing inherently wrong with using upper-case, it's just ugly as F.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is adding tbody before the thead, changed that to append Thead tr first and then tbody.

```
var selected = [];
var kapacitet = [];
var cena = [];
var hp = [];
var niza = [];
var finalKola = [];
 function addTable() {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "";
        var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("results")
        var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY')

        myTableDiv.border = '1'


        var heading = []; 
                heading[0] = "Бренд"
                heading[1] = "Модел"
                heading[2] = "Капацитет"
                heading[3] = "Коњски сили"
                heading[4] = "Цена"


        //koloni 
        var tr = document.createElement('TR');
        tableBody.appendChild(tr);
        for (a = 0; a < heading.length; a++) {
            var th = document.createElement('TH')
            th.width = '75';
            th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(heading[a]));
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }
        myTableDiv.appendChild(tableBody);  
        //table rows
        for (a = 0; a < finalKola.length; a++) {
            var tr = document.createElement('TR'); 

                var td = document.createElement('TD')
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(finalKola[a].Brand));
                tr.appendChild(td);
                var td = document.createElement('TD')
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(finalKola[a].Model));
                tr.appendChild(td);
                var td = document.createElement('TD')
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(finalKola[a].engineCap));
                tr.appendChild(td);
                var td = document.createElement('TD')
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(finalKola[a].sili));
                tr.appendChild(td);
                var td = document.createElement('TD')
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(finalKola[a].amount + " €"));
                tr.appendChild(td);

            tableBody.appendChild(tr); 

        }

    $(document).ready(function (){
                    {
                        $('#results').dataTable();
                    }
             });
    }
```

Comment: I am sorry but I just don't get what you are saying. You are saying that first I need to create the Thead and they the Tbody?

Comment: the reason is your html table is not well formatted, can you post your HTML?

Comment: I have added my entire HTML code in the original post.

Comment: Did my answer helped you?

Comment: i tried changing my code exactly as you suggested but it's still not workign